# Why is javax.money.CurrencyUnit not Serializable?

Tags: java, hibernate, java-money, jsr354

Why does `javax.money.CurrencyUnit` not extend from `java.io.Serializable`? All of its subtypes implement `java.io.Serializable`, and on top of that, if you want to use it in your hibernate mapping, then findbugs will stop you (quite correctly) because:

```
[INFO] Class com.mycompany.SiteEntity defines non-transient non-serializable instance field defaultCurrency [com.mycompany.SiteEntity] In SiteEntity.java
[INFO] Class com.mycompany.SiteEntity defines non-transient non-serializable instance field supportedCurrencies [com.mycompany.SiteEntity] In SiteEntity.java
[INFO] Class com.mycompany.UserEntity defines non-transient non-serializable instance field sessionCurrency [com.mycompany.UserEntity] In UserEntity.java
```

Does this mean that one must use the class `JDKCurrencyAdapter` in one's hibernate mapping? I'd much rather prefer to use the interface, but if it is not possible then I'll use the class.

Comment: probably because CurrencyUnit is an interface, and it already extends another interface, so it cannot multiple extend another interface. You can always wrap them in a custom class and implement Serializable.

Comment: good question, especially because `CurrencyUnit` states that all implementations *should be serializable (on platforms providing serialization).* You could ask this on https://github.com/JavaMoney/jsr354-api/pulls

Comment: @wero *implementations* should be serializable. You notice OP pointed out that all of it's subtypes do indeed extend (or implement) Serializable, so OP's custom classes need to implement Serializable as well.

Comment: @SnakeDoc but what to do if your field type is `CurrencyUnit`

Comment: @wero That's fair. It doesn't appears they ever intended someone to use `CurrencyUnit` as a type, but rather to always implement it in a concrete class. Perhaps they should add an abstract class and have it implement `CurrencyUnit` and `Serializable`. like this example class `TestCurrency implements CurrencyUnit, Serializable, Comparable<CurrencyUnit>`

Comment: The ordinary Serialization mechanism doesn’t care whether the instance field’s type (i.e. `CurrencyUnit`) is serializable, all it cares about is whether the actual runtime value/object in that field is serializable. That’s why `ObjectOutputStream.writeObject` has the parameter type `Object` rather than `Serializable`…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Static checks against `Serializable` are completely unreliable, in both directions.  The FindBugs warnings here are well-intentioned, but shouldn't stop you from using `CurrencyUnit` as you are now.

A class can have a field

```
Object aSerializableObject
```

and be serializable, even though the static type of the field is not -- as long as it ensures that references placed in this field are serializable.  So the static check against `Serializable` produces false negatives.

It also produces false positives; implementing `Serializable` is no guarantee that instances will serialize without exception; it is merely a statement of design intent.

Bottom line: while it masquerades as a static-typing feature, serializability is in reality a dynamic-typing feature.  Static checks (whether within the code, such as `<T extends Serializable>`, or external checks, such as these FindBugs warnings) are merely hints as to where something might go wrong.